# Шаблонный конструктор с переменным кол-вом параметров, который принимает объекты класса

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

Имеется шаблонный класс матрица и данный конструктор с переменным кол-вом параметров

```
template<class T>
TMatrix<T>::TMatrix(int row, int col, T el, ...) : TMatrix(row, col, &el) {

}

template<class T>
TMatrix<T>::TMatrix(int row, int col, const T *arr) {
    if (row < 0 || col < 0) throw " ";
    if (row * col == 0) {
       this->row = 0;
       this->col = 0;
       this->arr = nullptr;
    }
    else {
       this->row = row;
       this->col = col;
       this->arr = new T[this->col * this->row];
       for (int i = 0; i < this->row * this->col; i++) {
           this->arr[i] = arr ? arr[i] : 0.0;
       }
   }
}
```

Всё работает со встроенными типами данных, но когда я хочу передать в качестве параметра шаблона другой класс, то конструктор копирования вызывается только для объекта f1, остальные не копируются

```
Fraction f1(2, 3);
Fraction f2(3, 4);
Fraction f3(3, 4);
TMatrix<Fraction> m(1, 3, f1, f2, f3);
```

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, это не "работает" ни с какими типами данных. Кто вам разрешил осуществлять доступ к `...`-параметрам через некий указатель на предыдущий параметр? Где вы вообще выкопали эту идею?

Доступ к `...`-параметрам осуществляется через механизм `<cstdarg>`: `va_list`, `va_arg` и т.д. Никаких других вариантов нет.

Во-вторых, передача в качестве `...`-аргументов объектов с нетривиальным конструктором копирования является условно-поддерживаемой и обладает семантикой, определяемой реализацией. (А до С++11 поведение в таком случае было вообще не определено.)

Почему вы решили, что для таких аргументов должен вызываться конструктор копирования? Вы нашли такую гарантию в документации к вашей реализации?

Comment: Ну, данную идею откопал преподаватель, дабы "избежать дублирования кода". А насчёт копирования, я не решил, просто было бы логично, если бы оно выполнялось, как в случае с обычными параметрами.